# Mongo DB - Setup as Infrastructure as Code

Tags: mongodb, terraform, mongodb-atlas

We are in the process of creating a new Database using Mongo DB Atlas and we are checking the possibility of setting up the entire setup (Project, Cluster, Database, Collections, Users etc.) using Infrastructure as Code. This will enable us to setup a new environment easily using the scripts. We saw few options like Terraform Templates (https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-vscode/create-cluster-terraform/). But this will setup only the project, cluster and database users. We do not see a way in setting up databases or collections. Is there any documentation or guidance around how to spin up Mongo DB using IaC?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform provider for Mongodb Atlas: where is my db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150866/terraform-provider-for-mongodb-atlas-where-is-my-db)

Answer (score 0):

The following is the mongodb atlas terraform provider: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mongodb/mongodbatlas/latest/docs/resources/database_user this can be used to interact with the resources supported by MongoDB Atlas.
There you can check all the available provider resources and data sources.

Comment: Please add your answer as  a comment or explain more by yourself.